# does hiding elements in responsive lay-out affects loading time less?

Tags: bootstrap-4

When using the hiding elements classes from bootstrap 4 I get multiple designs possible for mobile and pc.

But when certain elements are hidden on mobile as example, will the loading time be shorter too?

Comment: everything in your html will get loaded. Some browsers may not load images that are hidden, but you should be able to test this really quick. But aside from images (and maybe hidden videos) everything is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! so when i "can" use less element hiding, it is better for the loading time aswell right? Because a smaller code is better for the loading time?

Comment: you should not hide too much. You should rather only rearrange elements. Why is something important on mobile that you would hide it on desktop? Why not just leave it out everywhere? Or why just show it on medium devices? Why not everywhere?

Comment: I understand:) Thanks! Only question, when the whole code is loaded, could the loading time be longer because after loading everything, the elements that need to be hidden, need to be hidden? (don't know if this works like this, or that the code is being loaded from top to bottom) (i'm quite noob to this subjects about loading time, so just wondering ;) )

Comment: read something [like this to get an overview](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-browser-rendering-works-behind-the-scenes-6782b0e8fb10/) on how this works.

Comment: Thanks! That has made a lot clear to me! :)